# Unable to trigger longPress gesture [UiView]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm quite new to iOS and objective c in particular and I'm facing an issue were I'm unable to properly register a long press gesture recognizer to my view. I'm a little bit confused because I already added a tap gesture recognizer in a similar way and it worked fine.
This is how I add my long press gesture recognizer :

```
            UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(onTap:)];
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer * longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(longPress:)];

            [_pdfView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
            [_pdfView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

This is my longPress function:

```
-(void) longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"longPress");
  
}
```

This is my header file :

```
@interface FLTPDFSandboxController : NSObject <FlutterPlatformView, CustomPdfViewDelegate>

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

-(void) onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
-(void) longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;



- (UIView*)view;

@end
```

The tap gesture is working fine for me. It is just de long press one that is not triggered consistently. In fact in some very rare times it is triggered in a somewhat random manner.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't use Flutter, so can't really say, but... if your Tap method is being called, try adding this line: `NSLog(@"%@", [_pdfView gestureRecognizers]);` and see what you get. It's possible Flutter (or something else) has added conflicting gesture recognizers.

Comment: @DonMag how would you know if gesture recognizers are conflicting each other ?

Comment: Well, first step is to see if there ***are*** multiple gesture recognizers...

Comment: I checked and there is in fact multiple gesture recognizers.  there is tapGestureRecognizers and long press one's

Comment: OK - then you'll need to dig into the code you haven't written and find the gesture recognizers and figure out what they're doing, and whether or not you can remove or override them.

Comment: okay thank you for your help

Comment: A quick google search comes up with this on the Flutter docs: `gestureRecognizers property` -- "Which gestures should be forwarded to the PlatformView." --- probably a good place to start.

Comment: Seems your tap gesture recognizer is stealing touches from your long press gesture recognizer. Try setting cancelsTouchesInView property of tap gesture recognizer to false